# MQL custom indicator calling another custom indicator

Tags: mql4, indicator

I know how to call a custom indicator from an EA but would like to call a custom indicator from another custom indicator which I cannot manage to do.  The compiler does not give me any errors.  Is this possible to do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you're trying to do. Remember that SO is a code oriented help site, so it's very unlikely you'll get any help without showing what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely same approach -

`double value=iCustom(Symbol(),Period(),indicator_name,/* custom indicator buffer parameters separated by comma */,buffer,shift);` - no difference between ea and indicator